# Return value from Extension Function?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-places-api

I have a problem in which when I select a `UITextField`, out pops up a view controller where the user can type into a search bar and search for particular items via the Google Places API. It looks something like this:

```
//When clicking on the UITextField, this function is called
@IBAction func selectLocation(){
    gpaViewController.placeDelegate = self
    presentViewController(gpaViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Through a the GooglePlacesAutocomplete github I found online: https://github.com/watsonbox/ios_google_places_autocomplete the below Extension was written for me so that everytime you select an entry from the `UITableView` from the presented `gpaViewController`, the `place.description` is printed along with its `details` as shown below:

```
extension EventFormController: GooglePlacesAutocompleteDelegate {
    func placeSelected(place: Place){
        var test: Place?
        println(place.description)
        place.getDetails { details in
            println(details)
        }
    }

    func placeViewClosed() {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

However, upon doing so, I want it so that I can return the `place.description` from the `placeSelected` function as shown above but I am not too sure on how to do so. I tried to edit the `placeSelected` function inside the library but I don't think you can return anything from the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` `UITableView` function.

```
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  delegate?.placeSelected?(self.places[indexPath.row])
}
```

Any ideas on how to return the `place.description` and set that `place.description` as the text inside the `UITextField` after selecting an option? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

func placeSelected(place: Place) is an protocol method, you can't change the signature by adding a return value without breaking the callback chain, i.e, if you change the signature of the protocol method, it won't be called. Instead of returing place.description from the function, you're supposed to use it for updating your UI, for example:

```
func placeSelected(place: Place){
    var test: Place?
    println(place.description)

    // update UI
    textField.text = place.description // assuming that your EventFormController has reference to the textField you're trying to access

    place.getDetails { details in
        println(details)
    }
}
```

It would be better though if you can explain more concretely what you're trying to achieve. I still don't understand the connection between your placeSelected and the didSelectRowAtIndexPath implementations.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
place.getDetails { details in
  self.textField.text = details.name
}
```

I didn't read through the documentation but I believe getDetails is a function something like getDetail(completionHandler: (Details) -> Void), which completionHandler is a closure executed after details are fetched.

So I guess what you want to do after fetching the data is to let your textField in your view controller to display the information fetched.